# How to Check Server is accepting connections

Tags: c#, sockets, telnet, tcpclient, smpp

I just want to check if smpp server is accepting connections. As we can check it using command prompt with the following command: `telnet 152.26.53.39 2775` I simply want  to code this command in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
      try
           {
                tcpClient.Connect("152.26.53.39", 2775);
                Console.WriteLine("Port 2775 Open");
            }
      catch (Exception){

               Console.WriteLine("Port 2775 Closed");
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ping class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as below :

```
string nameOrAddress="152.26.53.39 2775";
public static bool PingHost(string nameOrAddress)
{
    bool pingable = false;
    Ping pinger = new Ping();

    try
    {
        PingReply reply = pinger.Send(nameOrAddress);

        pingable = reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
    }
    catch (PingException)
    {
        // Discard PingExceptions and return false;
    }

    return pingable;
}
```